# Network error while connecting to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, jsp

I am using sql server 2008 and jtds driver to establish a connection between sql server and the jsp application. I code i used is

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
     String url= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1/sfts";
String id= "sfts";
String pass = "sfts";
try{
     Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
     con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);
    }catch(Exception e){
                out.println(e);
     }
```

While running this code, it showing error as

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

TCP/IP was set enabled and port number was set to 1433. But still it is showing this error.. What to do now??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Goto AllProgram->SQL Server 2008->configuraton tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->
Select your server instance and right click on TCP/IP then goto IPAddresses. Change/Place port number for all IP's as 1433. Save it and restart the server. 
It Should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I use SQL EXPRESS 2014. I went to All Programs->SQL Server 2014->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
Right clicked on TCP/IP. In the TCP/IP Window, went to the option IPAll, then writed 1433 in TCP Port textbox. 
Restarted the SQLEXPRESS Service and the connection worked as expected.
Hope this help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make Sure that your SQL Server Browser service is active.
2. Perform the check as said by @RAVITEJA SATYAVADA. Also make sure that the IP Addresses in the IP Address tab is Enabled.